# DLRS unmanaged Installation

Tags: unmanaged-package, dlrs

I want to install the unmanaged dlrs package
I only saw the managed link and on the github a suggestion to use convert and deploy.
can you please direct me how?

Comment: Where are you stuck? Have you tried using the `sfdx` CLI to deploy the package?